# Angularjs radio button group, form valid without any selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On an angularJS application I have a `<form>` with a group of radio buttons, I want to force the user to select an option before he validates the form.

Here a simplify version of my HTML code :

```
  <form name="myForm">
    <label ng-repeat="option in options">
      {{option.name}}
      <input type="radio" name="animalOptions" value="option.id" required>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">
      SUBMIT
    </button>
    <h1>
    {{myForm.$valid}}
    </h1>
  </form>
```

I reproduced my issue in this example :

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecak2t61/3/)

Why does it prints **true** instead of **false** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set ng-model to keep the selected value, e.g. $scope.selected (required needs ng-model to work). Also a function is needed to set the model on every click. Validation can be done like this:

```
 <label ng-repeat="option in options">
    {{option.name}}
    <input type="radio" name="animalOptions" value="option.id" ng-model="selected" ng-click="toggle(option.id)" ng-required="!selected">
  </label>
```

ng-required="!selected" ensures that user has selected an option
Check this example: [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fyoLwqv3/27/)

Answer (score 0):

You need ng-model to set validity of your form input(s).
And use

> **required**

like this in Angular way :

> **ng-required="true"**

Something like this :

```
<form name="testForm" ng-submit="yourSubmitFunction();" novalidate>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="rr" value="optionA" ng-required="true"/> optionA
    <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="rr" value="optionB" /> optionB
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```